# Return to LWC after adding new record

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC that I have built that is used for the account layout.  On that page I have a button to create a new related record.  When I click that button, it opens the modal to create the new record.  However, after I save the record, it directs to the page layout for the newly created record.  I would like it to close the modal and stay on the account LWC.  Is there a way to do that?  Here is what I am using to open the new modal:  thanks!!!

```
 this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'standard__objectPage',
  //type: 'standard__recordPage',
  attributes: {
      objectApiName: 'UWI__c',
      actionName: 'new'
  },
  state: {
    defaultFieldValues: defaultValues,
    recordTypeId: recType,
    nooverride: "0"
  }
```

});